# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while creating binary tree of given height

Tags: c++, tree, segmentation-fault

This is my first time working with trees. I wrote a c++ code, but it says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` , As far as I searched, this error comes from accessing a memory location that may be NULL. I tried 'new' keyword as malloc() should be avoided in c++,  But still I didn't get how to resolve this in my code.

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
}*next;

int k=0;

void tree(int i,/*struct*/ node *next = new node)
{
  ++k; --i;
  if (i==0)
    return;
  //next = new node;
  next->data = k*k;
  next->left = NULL;
  next->right = NULL;
  tree(i, next->left);
  tree(i, next->right);
  return ;
 }

 void display (node* next)
 {
  cout<<next->data<<" ";
  if (next->left!=NULL)
    {
        display(next->left);
        display(next->right);
    }
 }
 int main()
 {
   int h;
   cout<<"Enter the expected height of tree : ";
   cin>>h;
   node *root;
   root = new node;
   root->data=0;
   root->left=NULL;
   root->right=NULL;
   tree(h, (root->left));
   tree(h, (root->right));
   cout<<root->data<<" ";
   display(root->left);
   display(root->right);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What input are you giving to the program, i.e., what is the initial value of h?

Comment: Any integer. Even if cout/cin statements are replaced by h=3; i.e. may be any constant, still Segmentation fault exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

void tree(int i, struct node **root, int k)
{
    if (i < 1)
        return;

    *root = new struct node;
    (*root)->data = k*k;
    (*root)->left = NULL;
    (*root)->right = NULL;
    tree(i - 1, &((*root)->left), k + 1);
    tree(i - 1, &((*root)->right), k + 1);
}

void display(struct node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    cout << root->data << " ";
    if (root->left != NULL) 
        display(root->left);
    if (root->right != NULL)
        display(root->right);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root;
    int h;

    cout<<"Enter the expected height of tree : ";
    cin>>h;
    tree(h, &root, 0);
    display(root);
    return 0;
}
```

I think you should do some more read up on how pointers works: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

When you where calling `tree(h, root->left)` you actually just send the pointers value "NULL" == 0x0. As you want to allocate memory for it you should send a reference to the pointer. Hence &root and &((*root)->left). In the display function you have to check for NULL values both for left and right.

The code above is only improved and doesn't handle any freeing of memory, to be able to do that, traverse the tree and use delete on all leafs and work you back to the root.

Comment: I should have passed parameters by reference. And that's why you always passed address of current node.Learnt a new thing, pointer to a pointer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are serious problems with this code. In particular, here:

```
void display (node* next)
{
  cout<<next->data<<" ";
  if (next->left!=NULL)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

You dereference `next` without ever checking to see whether it's null. And it will be null. That's enough to explain the error you see.

I say that it will be null because of this:

```
void tree(int i,/*struct*/ node *next = new node)
{
  ...
  return ;
}

...
root->left=NULL;
...
tree(h, (root->left));
...
display(root->left);
```

The `tree` function takes its second argument by value-- that means that it does not change the value of `root->left`. You then call `display` with a null argument. I suspect that you think `void tree(int i,/*struct*/ node *next = new node)` means something other than what it actually means.

More fundamentally, you must review the two ways to pass an argument, by reference and by value.

More fundamentally still, you must start with a small, simple program and build up in small steps, rather than trying to write a big complex program all at once.

Comment: Yes I was wrong, I should have passed arguments by reference and not by value.